# Is there any way to create a JavaFX TableView that looks like this?

Tags: java, javafx

[image]

I'm trying to create a TableView with 4 columns that looks like the image above. As you can see it should be separated into sections called "Logements" and "Commerces". The titles Logements and Commerces take up the entire width of the table as if their rows only have one single column instead of four. Is this possible? Here is the generic tableView code I wrote:

```
@FXML
private TableView<FacilityRow> accommodationsOrBusinessesTableView;
@FXML
private TableColumn<FacilityRow, String> numberTableColumn;
@FXML
private TableColumn<FacilityRow, String> typeTableColumn;
@FXML
private TableColumn<FacilityRow, String> heatingValueTableColumn;
@FXML
private TableColumn<FacilityRow, String> measurementCenterTableColumn;

@Override
public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {

    numberTableColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<FacilityRow, String>("number"));
    typeTableColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<FacilityRow, String>("type"));
    heatingValueTableColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<FacilityRow, String>("heatingValue"));
    measurementCenterTableColumn
            .setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<FacilityRow, String>("measurementCenter"));
}
```

And the FacilityRow class:

```
public class FacilityRow {

    private String number;
    private String type;
    private String heatingValue;
    private String measurementCenter;
    
    public FacilityRow() {
    }
    
    public FacilityRow(String number, String type, String heatingValue, String measurementCenter) {
        super();
        this.number = number;
        this.type = type;
        this.heatingValue = heatingValue;
        this.measurementCenter = measurementCenter;
    }

    public String getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(String number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getHeatingValue() {
        return heatingValue;
    }

    public void setHeatingValue(String heatingValue) {
        this.heatingValue = heatingValue;
    }

    public String getMeasurementCenter() {
        return measurementCenter;
    }

    public void setMeasurementCenter(String measurementCenter) {
        this.measurementCenter = measurementCenter;
    }
}
```

Comment: `TableView` isn’t really designed for this, and as far as I know making this work would require a lot of effort, and probably result in code that is a bit difficult to maintain. I think my approach would be 1. add extra items in the backing list to represent the headers, which would probably have null values for all properties except `type`, 2. use a `rowFactory` on the table which sets a custom CSS pseudoclass on the row when displaying a header 3. write external CSS that hides the cell borders for table cells in the header row. Other approaches may be possible.

Comment: Also consider a `TitledPane` with a `TableView` for each section.

Comment: Consider a [`TreeTableView`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/tree-table-view.htm).  It won't be exactly the same as image in the question, but may provide an alternate way of achieving a similar (but slightly different) functionality, look and feel.

Comment: Similarly, ControlsFX has [SpreadsheetView](https://controlsfx.github.io/javadoc/11.1.0/org.controlsfx.controls/org/controlsfx/control/spreadsheet/SpreadsheetView.html#getColumnSpan(org.controlsfx.control.spreadsheet.SpreadsheetCell)) which has column spanning.  It is a bit further from what you want though, TreeTableView is closer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TableView isn’t really designed for that, but you can customize TableCells in a subclass of [TableRowSkin](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/20/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/skin/TableRowSkin.html) to achieve the column-spanning effect:

```
private static class SectionTableRowSkin
extends TableRowSkin<FacilityRow> {
    SectionTableRowSkin(TableRow<FacilityRow> row) {
        super(row);
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateCell(TableCell<FacilityRow, ?> cell,
                              TableRow<FacilityRow> row) {

        super.updateCell(cell, row);

        if (row instanceof SectionTitleTableRow titleRow) {
            if (row.getItem() instanceof SectionRow sectionRow) {
                List<TableColumn<FacilityRow, ?>> columns =
                    cell.getTableView().getColumns();

                int columnIndex = columns.indexOf(cell.getTableColumn());
                if (columnIndex == 0) {
                    DoubleExpression width =
                        columns.stream()
                            .map(c -> (DoubleExpression) c.widthProperty())
                            .reduce(DoubleExpression::add)
                            .orElseGet(
                                () -> new SimpleDoubleProperty(0));
                    cell.minWidthProperty().bind(width);
                    cell.prefWidthProperty().bind(width);
                    cell.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
                } else {
                    cell.minWidthProperty().unbind();
                    cell.prefWidthProperty().unbind();
                    cell.setPrefWidth(0);
                    cell.setMaxWidth(0);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And you can render the “section title” rows by setting an infinitely wide rectangle as the graphic:

```
private static class NumberCell
extends TableCell<FacilityRow, String> {
    private static final Color TITLE_COLOR = Color.valueOf("#2b529d");

    private final ImageView logementIcon = new ImageView(
        SectionedTable.class.getResource("logement.png").toString());

    private final ImageView commerceIcon = new ImageView(
        SectionedTable.class.getResource("commerce.png").toString());

    int getTypeCount() {
        List<?> items = getTableView().getItems();
        int size = items.size();
        int first = getIndex() + 1;
        int last = size - 1;
        for (int i = first; i < size; i++) {
            if (items.get(i) instanceof SectionRow) {
                last = i - 1;
                break;
            }
        }

        return last - first + 1;
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(String value,
                              boolean empty) {

        super.updateItem(value, empty);

        FacilityRow f = getTableRow().getItem();
        if (f instanceof SectionRow sectionRow) {
            int count = getTypeCount();
            String text = sectionRow.getText(count);

            Label label = new Label(text);
            label.setTextFill(TITLE_COLOR);

            Region line = new Region();
            line.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
            line.setMinHeight(1);
            line.setPrefHeight(1);
            line.setMaxHeight(1);
            line.setBackground(new Background(
                new BackgroundFill(TITLE_COLOR, null, null)));

            HBox pane = new HBox(label, line);
            pane.setFillHeight(false);
            pane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
            HBox.setHgrow(line, Priority.ALWAYS);
            setText(null);
            setGraphic(pane);
        } else {
            if (empty || value == null) {
                setText(null);
                setGraphic(null);
            } else {
                setText(value);
                setGraphic(isLogement(f) ? logementIcon : commerceIcon);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a complete program demonstrating it:

```
import java.text.MessageFormat;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.Objects;

import javafx.beans.binding.DoubleExpression;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleDoubleProperty;

import javafx.geometry.Pos;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;

import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TableRow;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.control.skin.TableRowSkin;

import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.Background;
import javafx.scene.layout.BackgroundFill;

import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;

public class SectionedTable
extends Application {
    private static final Set<String> LOGEMENT_TYPES =
        Set.of("A", "B", "C", "D");

    private TableView<FacilityRow> table;

    private TableColumn<FacilityRow, String> numberTableColumn;
    private TableColumn<FacilityRow, String> typeTableColumn;
    private TableColumn<FacilityRow, String> heatingValueTableColumn;
    private TableColumn<FacilityRow, String> measurementCenterTableColumn;

    private static boolean isLogement(String type) {
        return type != null && LOGEMENT_TYPES.contains(type);
    }

    private static boolean isLogement(FacilityRow row) {
        return isLogement(row.getType());
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        numberTableColumn = new TableColumn<>("Numero");
        typeTableColumn = new TableColumn<>("Type");
        heatingValueTableColumn =
            new TableColumn<>("Valeur de chauffage (en W)");
        measurementCenterTableColumn = 
            new TableColumn<>("Centre de mesurage");

        numberTableColumn.setCellValueFactory(
            new PropertyValueFactory<FacilityRow, String>("number"));
        typeTableColumn.setCellValueFactory(
            new PropertyValueFactory<FacilityRow, String>("type"));
        heatingValueTableColumn.setCellValueFactory(
            new PropertyValueFactory<FacilityRow, String>("heatingValue"));
        measurementCenterTableColumn.setCellValueFactory(
            new PropertyValueFactory<FacilityRow, String>("measurementCenter"));

        numberTableColumn.setCellFactory(col -> new NumberCell());

        table = new TableView<>();
        table.getColumns().add(numberTableColumn);
        table.getColumns().add(typeTableColumn);
        table.getColumns().add(heatingValueTableColumn);
        table.getColumns().add(measurementCenterTableColumn);

        table.getItems().addAll(
            new SectionRow(new MessageFormat(
                "{0,number} {0,choice,0#Logements|1#Logement|1<Logements} ")),
            new FacilityRow("0101", "A", "4300", "CM-1"),
            new FacilityRow("0102", "B", "3750", "CM-1"),
            new FacilityRow("0103", "C", "2050", "CM-1"),
            new FacilityRow("0104", "D", "2550", "CM-1"),
            new SectionRow(new MessageFormat(
                "{0,number} {0,choice,0#Commerces|1#Commerce|1<Commerces} ")),
            new FacilityRow("0101", "Commerce A", "0", "")
        );

        table.setRowFactory(t -> new SectionTitleTableRow());

        stage.setScene(new Scene(new BorderPane(table)));
        stage.setTitle("Facilities");
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    private static class SectionRow
    extends FacilityRow {
        private final MessageFormat countFormat;

        SectionRow(MessageFormat countFormat) {
            this.countFormat = Objects.requireNonNull(countFormat,
                "Count format cannot be null.");
        }

        String getText(int count) {
            return countFormat.format(new Object[] { count });
        }
    }

    private static class SectionTableRowSkin
    extends TableRowSkin<FacilityRow> {
        SectionTableRowSkin(TableRow<FacilityRow> row) {
            super(row);
        }

        @Override
        protected void updateCell(TableCell<FacilityRow, ?> cell,
                                  TableRow<FacilityRow> row) {

            super.updateCell(cell, row);

            if (row instanceof SectionTitleTableRow titleRow) {
                if (row.getItem() instanceof SectionRow sectionRow) {
                    List<TableColumn<FacilityRow, ?>> columns =
                        cell.getTableView().getColumns();

                    int columnIndex = columns.indexOf(cell.getTableColumn());
                    if (columnIndex == 0) {
                        DoubleExpression width =
                            columns.stream()
                                .map(c -> (DoubleExpression) c.widthProperty())
                                .reduce(DoubleExpression::add)
                                .orElseGet(
                                    () -> new SimpleDoubleProperty(0));
                        cell.minWidthProperty().bind(width);
                        cell.prefWidthProperty().bind(width);
                        cell.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
                    } else {
                        cell.minWidthProperty().unbind();
                        cell.prefWidthProperty().unbind();
                        cell.setPrefWidth(0);
                        cell.setMaxWidth(0);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static class SectionTitleTableRow
    extends TableRow<FacilityRow> {
        SectionTitleTableRow() {
            setSkin(new SectionTableRowSkin(this));
        }
    }

    private static class NumberCell
    extends TableCell<FacilityRow, String> {
        private static final Color TITLE_COLOR = Color.valueOf("#2b529d");

        private final ImageView logementIcon = new ImageView(
            SectionedTable.class.getResource("logement.png").toString());

        private final ImageView commerceIcon = new ImageView(
            SectionedTable.class.getResource("commerce.png").toString());

        int getTypeCount() {
            List<?> items = getTableView().getItems();
            int size = items.size();
            int first = getIndex() + 1;
            int last = size - 1;
            for (int i = first; i < size; i++) {
                if (items.get(i) instanceof SectionRow) {
                    last = i - 1;
                    break;
                }
            }

            return last - first + 1;
        }

        @Override
        protected void updateItem(String value,
                                  boolean empty) {

            super.updateItem(value, empty);

            FacilityRow f = getTableRow().getItem();
            if (f instanceof SectionRow sectionRow) {
                int count = getTypeCount();
                String text = sectionRow.getText(count);

                Label label = new Label(text);
                label.setTextFill(TITLE_COLOR);

                Region line = new Region();
                line.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
                line.setMinHeight(1);
                line.setPrefHeight(1);
                line.setMaxHeight(1);
                line.setBackground(new Background(
                    new BackgroundFill(TITLE_COLOR, null, null)));

                HBox pane = new HBox(label, line);
                pane.setFillHeight(false);
                pane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
                HBox.setHgrow(line, Priority.ALWAYS);
                setText(null);
                setGraphic(pane);
            } else {
                if (empty || value == null) {
                    setText(null);
                    setGraphic(null);
                } else {
                    setText(value);
                    setGraphic(isLogement(f) ? logementIcon : commerceIcon);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static class FacilityRow {

        private String number;
        private String type;
        private String heatingValue;
        private String measurementCenter;
        
        public FacilityRow() {
        }
        
        public FacilityRow(String number, String type, String heatingValue, String measurementCenter) {
            super();
            this.number = number;
            this.type = type;
            this.heatingValue = heatingValue;
            this.measurementCenter = measurementCenter;
        }

        public String getNumber() {
            return number;
        }

        public void setNumber(String number) {
            this.number = number;
        }

        public String getType() {
            return type;
        }

        public void setType(String type) {
            this.type = type;
        }

        public String getHeatingValue() {
            return heatingValue;
        }

        public void setHeatingValue(String heatingValue) {
            this.heatingValue = heatingValue;
        }

        public String getMeasurementCenter() {
            return measurementCenter;
        }

        public void setMeasurementCenter(String measurementCenter) {
            this.measurementCenter = measurementCenter;
        }
    }
}
```